# How to export model with pivot in the center?

Tags: export, unity, origin, 3d-cursor

I'm trying to export a model as an .obj file from Blender and import it into Unity. In Blender the object has the pivot right in the center of the model, but when I put it into Unity the pivot appears at the bottom of the model. Here are a couple of images to better describe what I'm trying to explain:

Model in Blender:

[image: model_in_blender]

Model in Unity:

[image]

This disorientation causes problems with rotation, transformation, etc, in Unity. I want to know how this can be fixed. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the object selected in Object mode, press <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to reset the position of the object to the world center. Some exporters will consider your object origin to be the world center, so you won't have any issues if you center your object.

Comment: There's also a posting in the SE Unity site about this: https://forum.unity.com/threads/wrong-pivot-point-from-blender-to-unity.423176/

Comment: @JohnEason yes, I decided to post here because I thought it was something more related to Blender than Unity, but it's helpful too, thanks.

Comment: @Daniel You'll see that happen occasionally with two popular programs. Don't worry about it! The same thing occasionally happens with folks using Python in Blender. :^)